# Doxygen member groups and type hints with doxypypy in Python code

Tags: python, doxygen, documentation-generation

I'm using `doxygen` in combination with `doxypypy` to document Python source code.

```
class Test:
    """
    This is a test class.

    The thest class only serves the purpose of a MWE.

    Attributes:
        memberA (int): This is member A.
        memberB (int): This is member B.
        memberC (int): This is member C. A and B never invite C to their party.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.memberA = []
        self.memberB = []
        self.memberC = []
```

I now want to group members `A` and `B` in a [member group](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html) (by using `@{` and `@}` etc.) but several attempts of implementing this in the docstring were futile. What is the correct syntax of achieving this? (I'm quite new to Python in general, I'm coming from the C++ side... I'm using Google commenting style)

EDIT: Also, I failed to find out so far what formats I can use now. I know I can use doxygen special commands, but does `doxypypy` know how to read e.g. Google Style Doc?

EDIT2: I also discovered, that `doxygen`/`doxypypy` ignore the type hints... does anyone know how to include them?

EDIT3: Member groups can be used by using

```
##@{
#items in group
##@}
```

Comment: From the documentation (http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#pythonblocks halfway trough the paragraph): Note that in this case none of doxygen's special commands are supported.

Comment: As noted in my post I use `doxypypy` which is a tool to work with Python's docstrings

Comment: So what is the outcome of the doxypypy and handed to doxygen? When doxypypy doesn't translate the `"""` to e.g. `"""!` the note is still valid. Btw. doxygen has also its own python scanner so no reaal need for doxypypy unless doxypypy does some translations.

Comment: As far as I know, `doxypypy` enables (so does `doxypy`) usage of `doxygen`'s special commands inside Python's doc strings. Somewhere else I just right now saw that `"""!` you proposed and I'll immediately try. Also, the style I chose in the attribute section is still "Sphinx napoleon"ish, maybe that's also a problem?

Comment: I don't know "Sphinx napoleon" so it is hard to comment on it.

Comment: Ah, sorry, `napeolon` converts comments in Python doc strings that are written in e.g. Google Style or NumPy Style to `Sphinx`-readable restructured text

Comment: Regarding the Edit2. Which doxygen version are you using?

Comment: @albert It's version 1.8.15.  For now I built a custom alias which allows me to use something like `@type{int}` which looks quite nice, but a built-in solution would be more elegant of course

Comment: I read in another question that python nowadays has something like `self.memberA: int = 0` (which pep ?) in doxygen this could lead to a variable where the type of the variable is mentioned in the documentation of the variable declaration (currently not implemented in doxygen). Is this what you mean?

Comment: @albert Something like that or type hints in a function call. But as I said above, I use a custom doxygen macro as a work around.